# OpenDayLight SDN: Can't get openflow table info via OpenDayLight RESTCONF

Tags: openvswitch, openflow

I'm trying to connect several openflow OVS instances to OpenDayLight SDN.

My switches succesfully attached and I can get the nodes informations via the following RESTCONF request:

`/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes`

But I can't get openflow table information via a TABLE url.
Official documentation says I can use a RESTCONF request similar to:

`/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow:121062366427215/table=0`

But I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "error": [
            {
                "error-tag": "data-missing",
                "error-message": "Schema for '(urn:opendaylight:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)table' not found",
                "error-type": "protocol"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My opendaylight version is 4.4.2

What would be the proper way to get the openflow table information?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my platform.

After running (to enable all OpenFlow versions on OVS):

```
ovs-vsctl set bridge <bridge> protocols=OpenFlow10,OpenFlow11,OpenFlow12,OpenFlow13,OpenFlow14,OpenFlow15
```

the restconf requests now run fine.

I think there was a compatibility problem between OpenFlow versions and OVS, but I cannot tell more. Here is the webpage that helped me solve the issue: https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/openflow/